# INNER JOIN doesn't work based on 1 to 1 relationship with non nullable FK

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I'm new to EF Core and I'm trying to execute my query as `INNER JOIN`, but I get a `LEFT JOIN`. I have read documentation about when LEFT AND INNER JOIN work, but in my case based on my relationships `INNER JOIN` doesn't work.

If I understood it correctly I have to use required relationship between my entities and I will get INNER JOIN in my query. My FK is non nullable also, but this still doesn't work.

I'm able to achieve `INNER JOIN` with the `.Join()` method, but I would like to achieve this with easy way as `Include()` based on my relationships. I'm using EF Core 7.0.

Could someone explain why this doesn't work? Thanks in advance.

My entity configurations are like:

Parent

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Activity> builder)
{
    builder
        .ToTable("Activity")
        .HasKey("ActivityId");

    builder
        .HasOne(x => x.ConversationDetails)
        .WithOne(x => x.Activity)
        .HasForeignKey<ConversationDetails>(x => x.ActivityRefId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .IsRequired();

    builder
        .Property(e => e.ActivityId)
        .UseIdentityColumn()
        .IsRequired();
}
```

Child

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ConversationDetails> builder)
{
    builder
        .ToTable("ConversationDetails")
        .HasKey(x => x.Id);

    builder
        .Property(x => x.Id)
        .UseIdentityColumn()
        .IsRequired();

    builder
        .Property(x => x.Messages)
        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

    builder
        .Property(x => x.ActivityRefId) <- FK
        .IsRequired();
}
```

```
public class Activity
{
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public ActivityType? ActivityType { get; set; }
    public ActivityStatus ActivityStatus { get; set; }
    public int MeetingId { get; set; }

    public ConversationDetails ConversationDetails { get; set; } <- navigation property
}
```

```
public class ConversationDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Messages { get; set; }
    public int ActivityRefId { get; set; } 

    public Activity Activity { get; set; } <- navigation property
}
```

Code which I used

```
var result =  await _dbContext.Activity
                              .Include(x => x.ConversationDetails)
                              .ToListAsync();
```

Query from profiler

```sql
SELECT [a].[ActivityId], 
       [a].[ActivityStatus], 
       [a].[ActivityType], 
       [a].[EndDate], 
       [a].[MeetingId], 
       [a].[StartDate], 
       [c].[Id], 
       [c].[ActivityRefId], 
       [c].[Messages]
FROM [Activity] AS [a]
     LEFT JOIN [ConversationDetails] AS [c] ON [a].[ActivityId] = [c].[ActivityRefId]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your are querying `Activity`, EF is producing a `LEFT JOIN` to return all instances of `Activity`, including those without associated instances of `ConversationDetails`.

If you want to return only the instances of `Activity` that have associated instances of `ConversationDetails`, you can rewrite your query to produce a `List<ConversationDetails>` including `Activity`. For this query, EF should produce an `INNER JOIN`.

```
var result = 
       await _dbContext.ConversationDetails.Include(x => x.Activity)
      .ToListAsync();
```

Using [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async), you can rewrite it further to produce a `List<Activity>`.

```
using System.Linq.Async;
var result = 
    await _dbContext.ConversationDetails.Include(x => x.Activity)
    .AsAsyncEnumerable().Select(x => x.Activity).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tested this solution yesterday and I was confused, because other similar threads here related with my problem have different explanation about that. Required relationship/`INNER JOIN`, Option relationship/`LEFT JOIN`. I understand concept of that, based on your example:

If FK is non nullable, then row from dependent table has always matched row from parent.
If FK is nullable `LEFT JOIN` is used, because in some case row from parent table may not have row in dependent table.
Is it true?

Comment: @michał-cichoń, in arelationship, it is always possible for rows in the parent table to not have rows in the dependent table. If the FK is nullable, then it is also possible for rows in the dependent table to not have rows in the parent table.

Comment: Exactly! In a 1:n association the `n` can always be `0`, so if you ask EF to return `_dbContext.Activity` it can't do better than outer joining any 1:n association that's `Include`d. I once proposed an [`IncludeInner`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24955) method, but didn't meet much enthusiasm.

Comment: @MarceloEstriga Note that the query should be made distinct after `AsAsyncEnumerable`, for example by using `DistinctBy`.

Comment: @gert-arnold. No need to use `DistinctBy` in this case, since this is a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I overlooked that!

Comment: Summarized, I'm not able to achive `INNER JOIN` if my parent entity includes dependent entity(1 to1 relationship) and his FK is not null with query like: `await _dbContext.Activity.Include(x =>x.ConversationDetails).ToListAsync();`

Comment: @MarceloEstriga Thanks for help and explanation, your code works as I expected.